# Axosoft Report Builder (Active Reports 3) - Conditional Results Depending on Field Value

Tags: c#, report, conditional-statements, activereports

I am trying to create a custom report using Axosoft's Report Builder though I have one big issue to tackle.  The report will contain calculated totals and counts of the specific items that are pulled in from the database to display.  One such field (Custom_163) is a boolean where **true** will have it be one type of item (Enhancement) while **false** will have it as another (Maintenance).  I am able to get a count of the total amount of items in the report, but I want to break it down as percentages of the total.

**Problem:** One boolean field will determine two types of items.  Differentiating between them to gather a count of each is where I'm struggling.

**Initialized Variables:**

```
private bool _oddRow = true;

private string[] _labels = new string[3];

private int _defectsTotal = 0;
private int _enhanceTotal = 0;
private int _maintenTotal = 0;
```

**Detail Section (where it's creating the rows for the items):**

```
public void Detail1_Format()
{
    if  (rpt.Fields.Contains("Custom_163") && rpt.Fields["Custom_163"].Value != null)
    {
        if ((bool)rpt.Fields["Custom_163"].Value == true)
        {
            //needs something here to add a count towards this type
            return enhanceTotal;
        }
        else
        {
            //needs something here to add a count towards this type
            return maintenTotal;
        }

        _defectsTotal++;
        _enhanceTotal += enhanceTotal;
        _maintenTotal += maintenTotal;

        // To Color Every Other Row
        if (_oddRow)
        {
            rpt.Sections["Detail1"].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(224, 224, 224);
        }
        else
        {   
            rpt.Sections["Detail1"].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        }
        _oddRow = !_oddRow;     

        // Converting to String Values
        if (rpt.Fields["ItemId"].Value == null) return; 
    }
}
```

**The problem is specifically with these lines:**

```
if((bool)rpt.Fields["Custom_163"].Value == true)
```

I've changed this a ton from similar conditions:

```
if(rpt.Fields["Custom_163"].Value.ToString() == "True")
if(rpt.Fields["Custom_163"].Value == true)
if(rpt.Fields["Custom_163"].Value = true)
if(rpt.Fields["Custom_163"].Value == 1)
if(rpt.Fields["Custom_163"].Value.ToString() == "1")
if (Convert.ToBoolean(rpt.Fields["Custom_163"].Value) ==  true)
etc...
```

But they don't seem to work as intended.  I want it to filter out the items where this field is **true** so the rest will execute.

Another thing is returning the values from the if-else statement (not working and I've tried using a separate method below that doesn't work either):

```
public class findTotals
{
    public findTotals()
    {
    }
    public int resultTotals()
    {
        bool item = (bool)rpt.Fields["Custom_163"].Value;

        if ( item == true)
        {
            int enhanceTotal = 1;
            return; 
        }
        else
        {
            int maintenTotal = 1;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

(This whole method needs a ton of work TBH).

Lastly, these lines has to be outside of the second if-else or at least somehow returned to the original if in order to be printed to the report:

```
_enhanceTotal += enhanceTotal;
_maintenTotal += maintenTotal;
```

The _defectsTotal gets a total count of all the items and that works fine.  These two lines though are supposed to add a count based on the above conditions for each type so then the total amount of Enhancements and total amount of Maintenance Items get posted at the end of the report. It doesn't work, if not a casting/conversion error or the conditions force the array(s) out of bounds, it's some other issue. I've played around the order for all these too.

**Possible Solutions?**

1. How to safely convert (if needed) the bool values to int so that number can be used to add to a total?
2. How can I return the values in the if-else so the scope matches up with the variables? Will I need a method?

**Thank you in advance**.

Comment: Update: Using this one,    if (Convert.ToBoolean(rpt.Fields["Custom_163"].Value) ==  true)    seems to work, but I'm stuck on figuring out how to return the values again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the issue was.

So basically...

```
if (Convert.ToBoolean(rpt.Fields["Custom_163"].Value) ==  true)
{
    enhanceTotal++;
}
else
{
    maintenTotal++;      
}

_defectsTotal++;
```

(This is all within another if-statement and a bunch of code not relevant to issue.) This works fine and actually returns the count, after that another hurdle was figuring out the labels so it can print into it's placeholders correctly.  The whole findTotals method wasn't needed.  I didn't need any more variables than the three listed above to make it work.  A reason I kept on getting errors was because I tried to use one variable as a label to print into different places within the report which isn't allowed apparently.  Instead of using one label and sticking it everywhere, I made several that were identical and made sure to give them different names, etc.

So instead of X in three different report sections, X was X, Y, Z (all identical but different identifer) and stuck it where needed.  Man, it seems to obvious now, well thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do a string compare against "True".  i.e.

if(string.Compare(rpt.Fields["Custom_163"].Value.ToString(),  "True") == 0)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I figured out a way to make it all work with an expression above.